# Issue with installing eclipse

Tags: eclipse

first I downloaded and installed Java JDK 64 bit 8u121, then I downloaded 64 bit version of Eclipse Neon on website. Run as Admin, clicked Eclipse for Java, procces bar, after few seconds eror with log. Can't paste this log because this is too long, milion lines. What i can do?

Screen: https://zapodaj.net/images/786fc1553fff2.png
Error log: http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/XjWlUTlH/file.html

Comment: Did you download the Eclipse installer, or a package ZIP? Can you post the top part of the log that shows any error?

Comment: I downloaded installer exe. I made screenshot where it stops: https://zapodaj.net/images/786fc1553fff2.png

Comment: @Daven From your picture, it might be because the address that they're trying to fetch something from has two slashes right in the middle.  Could you edit your post to include that image?

Comment: I looked at the logs and I saw multiply error.

Comment: ERROR log: http://www13.zippyshare.com/v/XjWlUTlH/file.html